# chart_Series: How to format the x axis to remove the year?

Tags: r, quantmod

How can I remove the Year from the x axis so that it only shows the day and month? Also, is it possible to rotate the x axis dates by 90 degrees?

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY", from="2013-01-01", to=Sys.Date())
chart_Series(SPY,theme=myTheme)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cspy <- chart_Series(SPY )
cspy$Env$actions[[3]]
#------------------
expression(axt <- axTicksByTime(xdata[xsubset], format.labels = format.labels), 
    axis(1, at = axt, labels = names(axt), las = 1, lwd.ticks = 1, 
        mgp = c(3, 1.5, 0), tcl = -0.4, cex.axis = 0.9))
attr(,"frame")
[1] 1
attr(,"clip")
[1] TRUE
attr(,"env")
<environment: 0x11cddc148>
```

You need to save the attributes so they can be put back in and you need to change the format.labels to your new specifications and then use the names from the axt vector rather than their value. The `las` parameter is the rotation indicator for base graphics. See `?par`:

```
attrs <- attributes(cspy$Env$actions[[3]])
cspy$Env$actions[[3]] <- 
      expression(axt <- axTicksByTime(xdata[xsubset], format.labels = "%b %d"), 
         axis(1, at = axt, labels = names(axt), las = 2, lwd.ticks = 1, 
         mgp = c(3, 1.5, 0), tcl = -0.4, cex.axis = 0.9)) 
attributes(cspy$Env$actions[[3]]) <- attrs
cspy
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can do create your theme using

```
myTheme <- chart_theme()
myTheme$format.labels <- '%b %d'
chart_Series(SPY,theme=myTheme)
```

That should give you following

[image]

Comment: Rotation of the labels? (`chart_theme` throws an error with las=2.)

Comment: @DWin oh missed rotation of labels part.