# R quantmod manipulate x-axis

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm using `R` with `quantmod` to visualize some data

```
library(quantmod)

# calculate the dates before and after date of interest
t1 <- as.Date(as.character(20101018),"%Y%m%d") - 25
t2 <- as.Date(as.character(20101018),"%Y%m%d") + 10

# get historical data
current_Stock <- getSymbols("AAPL", src="yahoo", from=t1, to=t2, auto.assign = FALSE)

# plot this stuff
chartSeries(current_Stock, name = "AAPL", TA = NULL)
# mark day of interest
addTA(xts(TRUE,as.POSIXlt(as.Date(as.character(20101018),"%Y%m%d"))),on=-1, col="gray19")
```

which yields the following chart:

[image: My chart]

I now want the the Dates on the `axis` to be vertical (rotated by 90 Degree) and without the year like in the answer of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200119/chart-series-how-to-format-the-x-axis-to-remove-the-year) and then print the `day of interest` (where the gray bar is) in `bold` and in `gray`.

The result of the [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200119/chart-series-how-to-format-the-x-axis-to-remove-the-year) has the following chart:

[image: Not my chart]

But that solution is for `chart_Series` and I like the design and coloring of `chartSeries` from `quantmod` better.

How do I make

- The xaxis like in the second picture?
- Print the day under the grey bar in bold and gray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppress x-axis coming using rough method, `error` (As far as I know, it is the easiest) and `chartSeries(..., TA="add.TA.obj")` (because `addTA()` makes an axis). Then all that’s left is to make the axis what you want.

```
library(quantmod)

### preparation of data (the same as OP's)
t1 <- as.Date(as.character(20101018),"%Y%m%d") - 25
t2 <- as.Date(as.character(20101018),"%Y%m%d") + 10
current_Stock <- getSymbols("AAPL", src="yahoo", from=t1, to=t2, auto.assign = FALSE)

### [Edited] preparation of main plot data (I used 2010-10-15 as an interest day)
no_axis <- x <- chartSeries(current_Stock, name = "AAPL",  # be careful of ' and " in TA.block
                   TA = "addTA(xts(TRUE, as.POSIXlt(as.Date('20101015', '%Y%m%d'))), on=-1, col='gray19')", plot=F)

### make plot without x-axis
no_axis@x.labels <- "a"                 # throw something to x.labels to cause error
quantmod:::chartSeries.chob(no_axis)    # The error stops x-axis coming
  # try(quantmod:::chartSeries.chob(no_axis), silent = T)   # supprres warning version

### make x-axis (I used "x@colors$border" but original is "x@colors$major.tick")
interest <- which(strptime(x@x.labels, "%b %d %Y") == "2010-10-15")  # index of the day

par(mar = c(3.5, 3.5, 0, 3))   # I modified lab.position a little by padj.
axis(1, at = (1 + x@bp * x@spacing - x@spacing)[-interest], padj = 0.4,
     labels = (format(strptime(x@x.labels, "%b %d %Y"), "%b %d"))[-interest], 
     las = 2, mgp = c(3, 0.7, 0), col = x@colors$border, col.axis = x@colors$border)
axis(1, at = (1 + x@bp * x@spacing - x@spacing)[interest], padj = 0.4,
     labels = (format(strptime(x@x.labels, "%b %d %Y"), "%b %d"))[interest], 
     las = 2, mgp = c(3, 0.7, 0), col = x@colors$border, col.axis = "gray", font.axis=2)
```

[image]

Comment: wow, this is exactly what I was looking for. Nice code and beautiful output. This is working, when I execute it alone. I suppressed the error with `try(quantmod:::chartSeries.chob(no_axis), silent = T)` as the script didn't want to finish after the error. Do you have any tips on how to put this into a function? Because when putting the code into a function, `R` gives the following error: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'my_ta' not found` and I don't know, how to handle it.

Comment: OK, I can answer this myself: After trying a bit, I just put the code directly inside the TA block, so now it reads `no_axis <- x <- chartSeries(symbol_data, subset = curr_interval, name = stock_name, TA = "addTA(xts(TRUE, as.POSIXlt(dateOfInterest)), on=-1, col='gray19')", plot=F)` in one line instead two.

Comment: @user3079834; I felt your additional code is cool, so I edited :-)